# new XMLHttpRequest cannot run on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

The script below work perfectly in IE for the XML respond. But seems i cant figured out how to run on Firefox or Chorme. Try few modification but still not able to run it. Kindly need assistant.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
var xmlhttp;
var timeStamp;

var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate() //remove the + 1  afterwards
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var hour = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
var second = currentTime.getSeconds() + 1


timeStamp = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + second;



function on_click()

{



    var xmlToSend = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
    xmlToSend += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' ";
    xmlToSend += "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' ";
    xmlToSend += "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>";
    xmlToSend += "<soap:Body><Welcomescreen Sender='SENDERDDRESS' TimeStamp='28/10/2009 16:49:31' Type='1' Workshop='SG' RequireAppointmentDate='2010/01/04' xmlns='http://www.SENDERDDRESS.com/integration'/>";
    xmlToSend += "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    /


    var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
    xmldoc.loadXML(xmlToSend); 


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {/ / code
    for IE7 + , Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state_Change;

xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://SENDERDDRESS:4509/resd", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.mhe.com/SRP/requestVinRequest");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host", "SENDERDDRESS:4509");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", "391");
xmlhttp.send(xmldoc);



var objResponse = document.getElementsByTagName("Appointment");

objResponse.innerText = xmlhttp.responseXML.xml;

}

function state_Change()

{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            txt = "<table align='right' border='1' width='400'><tr><th><font color='#d9d7d7' size='4' face='verdana'>Time</font></th><th><font color='#d9d7d7' size='4' face='verdana'>Plate No.</font></th><th><font color='#d9d7d7' size='4' face='verdana'>Status</font></th></tr>";
            x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Appointment");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("AppointmentTime"); {
                    try {
                        txt = txt + "<td><font size = 5>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</font></td>";
                    } catch (er) {
                        txt = txt + "<td> </td>";
                    }
                }

                xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("NumberPlate"); {
                    try {
                        txt = txt + "<td><font size = 5>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</font></td>";
                    } catch (er) {
                        txt = txt + "<td> </td>";
                    }
                }

                xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("statusCode"); {
                    try {
                        txt = txt + "<td><font size = 5>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</font></td>";
                    } catch (er) {
                        txt = txt + "<td> </td>";
                    }
                }
                txt = txt + "</tr>";
            }
            txt = txt + "</table>";
            document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML = txt;
        } else

        {


        }

    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues. One is that you have a stray `/` just after the series of `xmlToSend +=` lines, which is a syntax error, and then there's this:

```
var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

`ActiveXObject` is not standard, it's an IE-specific thing. Unlike the other place you're using it, that line is not conditional.

You can just pass the `xmlToSend` string directly into `XMLHttpRequest#send` ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method)), you don't need to make an XML document out of it first. It'll just have to get turned back into a string again to be sent.

If you **really** want to actually create an XML document object, you can use [`DOMImplementation#createDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument) (e.g., `document.implementation.createDocument`) on compliant browsers.

**Off-topic**: JavaScript libraries can make your life a bit easier in the Ajax area (and many others). Something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) may save you some time.

Comment: T.J, I already move out the specific IE ActiveXObject and only using XMLHttpRequest to pass and in work in IE but still not in FF. However I did a TCP trace on both of the browser output and found out the XML header scheme in FF output differently and server respond was error.

Comment: Output send IE: POST /domain HTTP/1.1 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en-us Referer: http://localhost/appointment/welcome.html soapaction: http://www.domain.com/SRP/requestVinRequest Content-Type: text/xml User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Host: localhost:8080 Content-Length: 415 Connection: Keep-Alive Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: Output send FF:OPTIONS /domain HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 AskTbARS/3.8.0.12304 Firefox/3.6.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: soapaction,user-agent

Comment: @Arif: *"I already move out the specific IE ActiveXObject and only using XMLHttpRequest"* I'm talking about where you're creating the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` object, not the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Again, the code calling `ActiveXObject` to create the `XMLDOM` is **not** conditional (look just above where you branch when creating the `XMLHttpRequest`).